# How do I factorise this polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

I have the following polynomial:

$$y = 5 + 9x + 3x^2 -x^3$$

but I can't work out how to solve it for $y = 0$. The only thing I can think of is to try and guess a factor.

Comment: Did you try the rational candidates for the roots yet?

Comment: Apply the rational root theorem and you'll get a very nice, integer root.

Comment: Yes u r supposed to guess a root normally. Try x= 0,1 and -1 first

Comment: $-1$ is a root. DIvide by $(x+1)$ and get a polynomial of degree 2.

Comment: $x = -1$ is a root, so $(x+1)$ is a factor. divide it out by $(x+1)$ and get a quadratic. that should be easier to handle.

Comment: Did you try graphing it e.g. in Excel to get an idea where the roots are?

Comment: Well, if you consider resorting to Excel, you can better resort to http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-x%5E3+%2B+3x%5E2+%2B+9x+%2B+5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can factorize it this way:

$$x^3-3x^2-9x-5=x^3-3x^2-4x-5x-5=x(x-4)(x+1)-5(x+1)=(x+1)(x^2-4x-5)$$

then continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you try $1,-1,5,-5$, soon you will find $x=-1$ is a root.

So divide $f(x)$ by $(x-(-1))$ then you will have quadratic.

At the end $f(x)=-(x+1)(x+1)(x+5)$.

Comment: You can not get to your rep without learning a little MathJax. Sorry for being petty, but I will reverse my down vote when you change that.

Comment: I think downvoting is a little harsh, yet being a member here for more than one year, having close to 200 answers, and *not* using MathJax to write mathematics is also harsh.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Ust the rational root theorem, see: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem